# iOS top level navigation controller from AppDelegate Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, appdelegate

I am using this line:

```
var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
```

However, this only returns the root and not the top level nav controller. I am trying to push a view on top, but if the root controller is not the top level, The view is not on top.

I am trying to find out the navigation controller of the current view controller.

This is all to solve my problem of this error:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x7f8473d7c800> on <UINavigationController: 0x7f8472022600> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Define "top level" and from definition itself it must be clear already what to do.

Comment: The navigation controller of the current view

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there :

```
func topViewController() -> UIViewController? {
    if let rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController  {
        return rootViewController.topViewController 
    }
    return nil
}
```

Just be careful because there might also be another ViewController presented modally on top of your topViewController. You might want to check the `topViewController.presentedViewController` as well :

```
func topViewController() -> UIViewController? {
    if let rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController  {
        if let topVC = rootViewController.topViewController {
            if let modalTopVC = topVC.presentedViewController {
                return modalTopVC
            }
            return topVC
        }
        return rootViewController
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: I use            if let presentedViewController = self.presentedViewController {
            return presentedViewController.topMostViewController()
        } to check right?

Comment: I still run in to my old problem. When I push my view, it pushes on top of the old nav controller's stack and not my new one.

Comment: Then I'd need more context. Can you give more detail ? the rootViewController.topViewController is the view controller actually shown on screen, unless you did something weird with your view / viewcontroller hierarchy.

Comment: So when I start my app, it starts with its own NavController. Then I navigate to another NavController. Now when I want to push a view from my AppDelegate and I use rootViewController.topViewController it will push the view on the rootViewController and not the new one.       Heres the error: Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x7f8473d7c800> on <UINavigationController: 0x7f8472022600> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: Oh, right. Then, you need to look into self.topViewController().childViewControllers to see which one is your second navigationController.